# How to properly calculate Basketball team percent averages?

Tags: excel, powerbi

So I was making a dashboard for a personal project and I put some stats on a spreadsheet and made a column that calculated FG% based on (Field Goals Made/Field Goals Attempted) for each player. Now I threw this into Power BI and I want to calculate the team FG% average but Power BI takes the percentages as they are and averages them by taking all the percentages, adding them, and dividing by # of values. Of course, this is the normal way to find the average for General numbers but not percentages. How do I fix this and get the actual average FG%?

I apologize, I'm very new to this. [Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4pxv.png),[PowerBI Avg. Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0KHF.jpg)

For reference, this is the chart I'm trying to make in[PowerBI chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWm3l.png)

Comment: You may want to create another measure to divide the sum of FG by the sum of FGA of all players? You can also “weight” the players’ FG% and calculate the “weighted average” (which is essentially the same as the first calculation)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, now I just have to figure out how to make Power BI to give me the sum of the field goals made and the field goals attempted and use the sums of those columns to give me a team field goal percentage.